# Fonts appear in different sizes

Tags: fonts, luatex, pdf

I try to use my own font loader with LuaTeX and some fonts give me trouble. Perhaps others have come across the same problem and can help me.

[image]

These three fonts (Texgyre heros, [Inter-Roman](https://rsms.me/inter/) and Deja Vu condensed) are loaded at the same size, but the Inter Roman appears bigger

The PDF code is this:

```
BT
/F1 9.99999 Tf
1 0 0 1 28.346 804.543 Tm [<0070>60<001d>]TJ
/F9 9.99999 Tf
1 0 0 1 28.346 792.543 Tm [<01c4>62<0002>]TJ
/F13 9.99999 Tf
1 0 0 1 28.346 780.543 Tm [<0039>91<0044>]TJ
ET
```

Which are all 10pt fonts.

What makes the PDF viewer think that this font at 10pt is so big? How do other font handlers (Luaotfload) handle this?

A sample PDF is at https://github.com/speedata/publisher/files/5658559/publisher-q.pdf

Comment: Without seeing the code there isn't much we can tell you, but my crystal ball is telling me that you have to set `.units_per_em` correctly.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Thank you very much, that was exactly the problem! I wonder why this is not documented :-( (at least I could not find this in the documentation)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because from the comments it has been resolved.

Comment: Closing a possibly helpful question? Just because it has not been officially answered? So others cannot find it anymore? I don't think this is appropriate.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Linking to meta discussion on closing this question https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8716/2693

Comment: Sorry for any concerns brought by my voting for closing. Your comment "that was exactly the problem!" seems to indicate the resolution, hence to leave those truly help-wanted questions in the "unanswered" tab, I initiated the voting, maybe in a hurry. I will follow suggestions in linked question of [Stefan's answer](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8717/79060) next time. Last, my guess is that closed questions are still _searchable_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Marcel Krüger](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/80496/marcel-kr%C3%BCger) gave me the hint: I was missing the `.units_per_em` setting in the font table, which is at the time of writing not documented. It has to be set to the units per em which is given by the font.

Now TeX itself scales the font down properly so it can be used without any further action.

Reference in the LuaTeX tracker: http://tracker.luatex.org/view.php?id=200